# Hide plugin dashboard menu item for specific roles

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles

I am writing a plugin and I am trying to only display the admin dashboard menu item to specific roles.  I have this controlling snippet so far...

```
// Check User Role
 global $current_user;
  if( !empty($current_user->roles) ){
    foreach ($current_user->roles as $key => $value) {
      if( $value == 'administrator' ){
           new myplugin_Wp_List_Table();
      }
    }
  }
```

This isn't working for some reason, when i'm logged in as administrator it doesn't display the menu.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is a better strategy, that you add on the activation a new capability and add this capability to the Administrator role. This makes possible for installations with much different roles to the WP default to add this capability to other roles or for the requirement of a installation to add the view to another role.

#### Add Cap to a Role

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'fb_add_capabilities' );
function fb_add_capabilities() {

    `$GLOBALS['wp_roles']->add_cap( 'administrator', '_your_custom_cap' );`
}
```

#### Check for Cap

Inside your source can you check for this capabilty:

```
if ( ! current_user_can( '_debug_objects' ) )
    return;
```

#### Remove Cap

On the deactivation (Hook `register_deactivation_hook`) and uninstall (Hook `register_uninstall_hook`) of the plugin is it necessary, that you remove the cap.
`remove_cap()`

#### Example

A example in the wild can you finde in this [plugin, file](https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects/blob/master/debug_objects.php).

Comment: Much better way of doing it, thanks for the pointers